# How to put my dropdown select on the same line with my text using bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

How to put my dropdown select on the same line with my text? I want my drop down to be on the same line and make it shorter.

```
<div class="row mt-4 ">
   <p>1. Allowance For Yourself: Select 1 for yourself&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
   <div class="container">
      <select class="form-select" name="selT1">
         <option value="0" selected>0</option>
         <%for x=1 to 1
             if strT1=cstr(x) then%>
                <option value="<%=x%>" selected>&nbsp;<%=x%>&nbsp;</option>
             <%else%>                                            
                <option value="<%=x%>">&nbsp;<%=x%>&nbsp;</option>
             <%end if
         next%>
      </select> 
   </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2UJE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like this.... Your line of text and your form are now both inside columns which should be above each other on small screens but next to each other on medium screens and above.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row mt-4 ">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <p>1. Allowance For Yourself: Select 1 for yourself&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <select class="form-select" name="selT1">
         <option value="0" selected>0</option>
         <%for x=1 to 1
             if strT1=cstr(x) then%>
                <option value="<%=x%>" selected>&nbsp;<%=x%>&nbsp;</option>
             <%else%>                                            
                <option value="<%=x%>">&nbsp;<%=x%>&nbsp;</option>
             <%end if
         next%>
         </select> 
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've also restructured your container as it was inside a Row. Don't forget, in Bootstrap they Conainter, Row and Div has to be observed! They should only be nested like this...

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
```

As a side note `mt-4` in your Row is adding a margin to the top of the Row. Perhaps change that to `py-4` for top and bottom Padding only. You don't really need sideways padding on Row's.

Comment: my textbox is still on the bottom @Cute Code Rob

Comment: Hmmm, that's very annoying :) Do you have any CSS which is making 100% width of your form or any other global CSS affecting the form? Also did you restructure the container, row and column? I do feel that is going to be having an effect. Container first, Row inside it and then Column inside the Row as above.

Comment: Can you edited it in the code? @Cute Code Rob

Comment: Please see the second piece of code in my answer. You can only structure your Container, Row and Column in that way. In your original code this is not observed, you have a Container inside a Row.

Comment: this works but my spacing is still weird like my select is like tabs to the right